# Ctypes: OSError: exception: stack overflow

Tags: python, c++

#### C++

this code work in exe, but not working in dll when python is used.

Python throw this error when program run to `dec(&buffer2, &length, &buffer);` .

Both python and dll are x64.

```
#include "Decompress.h"
#pragma comment (lib,"Decompress.lib")

#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLLEXPORT void try_dec() 
{
    int buffer[20];
    int buffer2[20];
    int length = 20;

    dec(&buffer2, &length, &buffer);
    
    return;
}
```

#### Python

```
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.CDLL('Dec.dll')
dll.try_dec()
```

#### Error

```
    dll.dec()
OSError: exception: stack overflow
```

Comment: Im wondering what happens when you would rename this method in such a way that it doesn't have the same name as the method it calls

Comment: Please provide a [mre], what is `Decompress.h` and presumably the `dec` function it contains?

Comment: Sorry, I have changed (simplified) this code before, and made the same name is my mistake.but not a naming problem. I have edited

Comment: Still need a [mre], presumably your python should be `dll.try_dec()` otherwise its calling `dec` with the wrong number of arguments

Comment: yes, it's dll.try_dec(), But it's really not a naming problem. i don't know how provide a minimal reproducible example, but i can provide the lib(https://github.com/ladislav-zezula/StormLib).

Comment: I can't see `Decompress.h` in that repository either. There are instructions on the [mre] page of how to make one. At least make sure that the code you have posted reproduces the problem. e.g. if `buffer` and `buffer2` are larger than in the code you have posted they might not fit on the stack and cause a stack overflow

Comment: the `Decompress.h`is [StomLib.h](https://github.com/ladislav-zezula/StormLib/blob/master/src/StormLib.h). It may be a bit difficult to reproduce problem, because I don't know how provide this dll and lib. but you can compile this lib.[StormLib](https://github.com/ladislav-zezula/StormLib)

Comment: `StomLib.h` doesn't contain `dec`? Post your actual code not something that looks like your code. We can't debug your code for you if we can't see it

Comment: =_= ||   I suddenly realized that my function name is the same as the function witch in call function. Thank you very much.The problem is solved.

Comment: @Dylome: "***The problem is solved. function name duplicated.***" Don't edit the question and include the answer. Either post an answer or close the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

the function will call itself and you end up in an infinite loop resulting in the stack overflow. 
To prevent this sort of errors you should change your functions signature to

```
void dec (void)
```

Comment: only in c, the question is tagged c++ so presumably the OP is using c++?

Comment: Method is tagged as `extern "C"`, so I think it holds here

Comment: Sorry, I have changed (simplified) this code before, and made the same name is my mistake.but not a naming problem. I have edited

Comment: @JVApen nope: https://godbolt.org/z/RtlLD8, `extern "C"` only affects the name mangling