# ctypes allocate more memory to the stack

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a c-dll I call from python. The output from the dll is quite large and I suspect this causes an error

```
OSError: exception: stack overflow
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is the size of the output (roughly 4x25x720 doubles). Reducing the size of the output (which I do not want to do) makes the error go away.

In C# I can get around this problem by allocating more memory to the calling thread, i.e,

```
thread = new Thread(() => calculate(ptr_in, ptr_out), 20000000);
```

Is it possible to do something similar with `ctypes`?

This is NOT the problem posted here [Ctypes: OSError: exception: stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514845/ctypes-oserror-exception-stack-overflow).

---

### EDIT

Reflecting on the problem, I don't think the problem is the size of the output, but rather the space needed by the actual dll itself. I.e `c_out inner_out` defined in **ctypes_test.c**. Regardless, the problem is still the same.

---

In C I define a test dll `dll_ctypes_test`

**ctypes_testT.h**

```
#pragma once
#define N_ELEMENTS 1000
#define N_ARRAYS 50

typedef struct
{
    double var_0;
    double var_1;
    double var_2;
    double var_3;
    double var_4;
    double var_5;
    double var_6;
    double var_7;
    double var_8;
    double var_9;
} element;

typedef struct
{
    int n_elements;
    element elements[N_ELEMENTS];
} arr;

typedef struct
{
    int n_arrays;
    arr arrays[N_ARRAYS];
} c_out;
```

**ctypes_test.c**

```
#include "ctypes_testT.h"

__declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall dll_ctypes_test(double in, c_out *out)
{
    c_out inner_out;

    //Some caluclations on inner_out
    //Wrap values of inner arr to out
}
```

And the Python code

```
import ctypes

N_ELEMENTS = 1000
N_ARRAYS = 50

class element(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('var_0', ctypes.c_double),
                ('var_1', ctypes.c_double),
                ('var_2', ctypes.c_double),
                ('var_3', ctypes.c_double),
                ('var_4', ctypes.c_double),
                ('var_5', ctypes.c_double),
                ('var_6', ctypes.c_double),
                ('var_7', ctypes.c_double),
                ('var_8', ctypes.c_double),
                ('var_9', ctypes.c_double)] 

class arr(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('n_elements', ctypes.c_int),
                ('elements', element * N_ELEMENTS)] 

class c_out(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('n_arrays', ctypes.c_int),
                ('arrays', arr * N_ARRAYS)]     

dll = ctypes.WinDLL(r'C:\repos\ctypes_test\x64\Debug\ctypes_test.dll')

dll.dll_ctypes_test.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.POINTER(c_out)]  
dll.dll_ctypes_test.restype = None

dll.dll_ctypes_test(5, ctypes.byref(c_out()))
```

Calling the Python code produces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-7c8b287888d0>", line 1, in <module>
   dll.dll_ctypes_test(5, c_out())

OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x00000062BA400000
```

If I change `N_ARRAYS` from `50` to, say, `10`. The error goes away.

Comment: I would appreciate feedback on the down vote.

Comment: Most likely someone downvoted because of the poor quality in problem explanation. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
for more asking related details.

Comment: @CristiFati Duly noted, and thanks. I have now added code that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

I must say that I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior (even without fixing the errors below), using either "regular" *Python* or *IPython*. Maybe there's more to *dll_ctypes_test* implementation than meets the eye.

Current issues:

1. *dll_ctypes_test* expects a ***c_out* pointer**, but your'e passing a plain ***c_out* instance**. You should use *ctypes.byref* (or *ctypes.pointer*). Don't know why *CTypes* doesn't complain because of it
2. *C* and *Python* structure definitions don't match. One example is *arr* which contains an ***element* array** in *C*, and an ***element* pointer array** (*ctypes.POINTER*) in *Python*. This is *Undefined Behavior*, the 2 must be in sync
3. You marked the export function as *__stdcall*, but you're loading the *.dll* with *CDLL*. You should use *WinDLL*. But since you're on *064bit* (based on your paths), this doesn't make too much of a difference

Below it's an example (a modified version of your code).

*dll00.h*:

```c
#pragma once

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined DLL00_EXPORTS
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif

#define ELEMENT_COUNT 1000
#define ARRAY_COUNT 50


typedef struct {
    double var0, var1, var2, var3, var4,
         var5, var6, var7, var8, var9;
} Element;


typedef struct {
    int size;
    Element data[ELEMENT_COUNT];
} Array1D;


typedef struct {
    int size;
    Array1D data[ARRAY_COUNT];
} Array2D;


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API void __stdcall dll00Func00(double in, Array2D *pOut);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

*dll00.c*:

```c
#define DLL00_EXPORTS
#include "dll00.h"

#include <stdio.h>


void dll00Func00(double in, Array2D *pOut) {
    if (pOut == NULL) {
        printf("From C - NULL array passed\n");
        return;
    };
    Array2D arr2d;
    printf("From C - Outer array size: %d\n", pOut->size);
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import sys


ELEMENT_COUNT = 1000
ARRAY_COUNT = 50


class Element(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = list(("var{0:d}".format(i), ct.c_double) for i in range(10))


class Array1D(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("size", ct.c_int),
        ("data", Element * ELEMENT_COUNT),
    ]


class Array2D(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("size", ct.c_int),
        ("data", Array1D * ARRAY_COUNT),
    ]


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


def main(*argv):
    dll00 = ct.WinDLL(DLL_NAME)
    dll00Func00 = dll00.dll00Func00
    dll00Func00.argtypes = (ct.c_double, ct.POINTER(Array2D))
    #dll00Func00.argtypes = (ct.c_double, Array2D)  # !!! Defining the 2nd argument without POINTER, triggers the error !!!
    

    mat = Array2D()
    mat.size = 7
    #print(ct.sizeof(Element), Element._fields_, dir(Element))
    print("Array sizeof: {0:d} (0x{1:08X})".format(ct.sizeof(mat), ct.sizeof(mat)))

    dll00Func00(5, ct.byref(mat))
    #dll00Func00(5, mat)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060297181>sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2017\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.h
> dll00.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.h
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Array sizeof: 4000408 (0x003D0A98)
> From C - Outer array size: 7
>
> Done.
> ```

When calling a function or method (there are some exceptions, but those are irrelevant here), the stack (a special memory area) is used for storage. Common stuff being stored:

- Arguments (and return value),  which represent data exchanged between the *caller* and the *callee*
- Local variables (in the *callee*), which are neither static, nor explicitly allocated on the heap (via *malloc*, *new*, ...)
- Other data (invisible to the programmer, like *Instruction Pointer*, ...)

As expected, the stack is limited, so it can store a maximum amount of data. When the amount of data needed to be stored exceeds the maximum, *Stack Overflow* occurs (the most common scenario for the occurrence is during recursion, when there are too many recurring calls that need to store too much data).

Maximum stack size is determined by each application build options, and defaults vary depending on compiler, *OS*, *etc*. From [[MS.Docs]: /STACK (Stack Allocations)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations) (**emphasis** is mine):

> The reserve value specifies the total stack allocation in virtual memory. For ARM, x86 and x64 machines, the **default stack size is 1 MB**.

Same info can be found at [[MS.Docs]: /F (Set Stack Size)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size).

As seen, *Array2D* takes nearly ***4 MiB*** (so it wouldn't fit if / when attempted to be stored on the stack). 
As I specified in the comment (from *code00.py*), defining *dll00Func00*'s 2<sup>nd</sup> *argtype* **without *ct.POINTER*** triggers the error. Maybe there's such a typo in the code you're actually running?

Anyway, some general guidelines to avoid this error:

- Avoid passing (as arguments / return type) large amounts of data by value (the last 2 subpoints also apply to locally defined variables):

  - Use pointers (or references in *C++*)
  - Allocate them dynamically (on the heap)
  - Make them static (less desirable as static data segment is also limited)
- Make sure recursion doesn't go too deep (where applicable)
- Increase ("manually") the stack size when building an application

As a side remark, I don't think it's possible to increase (modify) the current process stack size in *C* under *Win* (*Visual C*). It is possible however in *C#* and also on *Nix* (*setrlimit*).

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer. Regarding the issues you point out, noted and corrected. I agree that the problem is not the input or output but the stack size. As I mention in my post it is possible to allocate more memory to the stack in C#. I was hoping this could be done for ctypes as well. I see that my post is badly formulated as all the code dectracts attention from that.

Comment: I don;t think it's possible (except recompiling *Python* with a higher stack size). But the important thing is you can avoid running into this issue (by following the guidelines when coding the *.dll*). Anyway I see that you got a totally different error. Than makes me think that the *C* function signature isn't the one you posted. P.S. the last line of your *.py* file, is not yet correct. did you try with my *.py* file? Still, **without being able to reproduce the error is kind of hard to fix it**.

Comment: I did try running your code. I get the same error (the last one). I tought I ran the code I posted (the one with all the bugs) when I got stack overflow error.

Comment: The last version of the code and the new exception don't match (the lines of code differ). So the stack overflow problem seems to be fixed, you have another (and nastier one). It's *Undefined Behavior*. Most likely it's in the *.dll* code. You should post the whole function. But I feel that it's the topic for another question, as it's totally different.

Comment: So, are you able to share *dll\_ctypes\_test* implementation? And also how do you build the *.dll*, and the *Python* version that you use?

Comment: Hi. My original implementation was as it was originally posted. But as you correctly pointed out it was rather buggy and it might be that the "stackoverflow" error occured as a result of some unknown bug. The actual code I use is too big to post. I have taken the points you made to heart and I think I see a way out of the problem. I will let the bounty stand until it expires and unless somebody has something clever to add I will mark your answer as "the answer" and award the bounty to you.

Comment: But noone can figure out the problem. It most likely lies in the *.dll* code. It's the classical ***Undefined Behavior*** sign. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011. It's no longer about not enough stack, but a crash.

Comment: Well, the problem was initially, and still is for that matter, if it is possible to allocate more memory to the stack (as you can for C#). The added code was an attempt to illustrate what happens when the dll is too large. As you mentioned in your post, in Python this cannot be done. The way I read your answer the only way out of this problem is to assign directly to the c_out input struct, omitting inner_out which resides only inside the dll. For me that is a good enough answer. I see no point in digging further into what happens in the code sample.I do very much appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Increasing the stack would only be a workaround, as there's no need for such big storage place. In *dll\_ctypes\_test* you could have `c_out *pInner_out = malloc(sizeof(c_out));` (and before **every** *return* statement `free(pInner_out);`, to avoid memory leaks). There's also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=vs-2019 (you'd have to call it from within the *.dll* as well), if you don;t want to allocate inner values on the heap.